# How to use Savitzky-Golay filter to fill gaps and smooth data in R

Tags: r

I want to know how to use the Savitzky-Golay filter in R to fill gaps and smooth my data.
This is my code, and my code JUST showed NA as results:

```
library(signal)
sg <- sgolay(p=1, n=3, m=0)
PLOT1500$sg <- filter(sg, PLOT1500$evi21500)
PLOT1500$sg
```

NA:

> PLOT1500$sg
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

My data sample is shown as follows:

```
   structure(list(system = structure(c(1459641600, 1459728000, 1459814400, 
1459900800, 1459987200, 1460073600, 1460160000, 1460246400, 1460332800, 
1460419200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    evi21500 = c(0.329, 0.328, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to know how to solve the NA problem, fill the gap, and smooth the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, and it comes if you load the signal signal before dplyr. Try loading signal later. The 2nd issue is that the filter length should be an odd number less than the number of data points.

```
library(dplyr)
library(signal)


 PLOT1500<-structure(list(`system:time_start` = structure(c(1451606400, 
1451692800, 1451952000, 1452038400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), evi1500 = c(0.437, NA, NA, 0.486), evi21500 = c(0.408, 
0.434, 0.434, 0.423), kndvi1500 = c(0.429, 0.532, 0.532, 0.525
), ndvi1500 = c(0.724, 0.773, 0.773, 0.788), nirv1500 = c(0.172, 
0.187, 0.187, 0.182), evi2500 = c(0.611, NA, NA, 0.579), evi22500 = c(0.576, 
0.426, 0.426, 0.539), kndvi2500 = c(0.417, NA, NA, 0.443), ndvi2500 = c(0.781, 
0.757, 0.757, 0.825), nirv2500 = c(0.286, 0.182, 0.182, 0.254
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

sg <- sgolay(p=1, n=3, m=0)
PLOT1500$sg <- filter(sg, PLOT1500$evi21500)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, but it still shows Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "sgolayFilter" ><

Comment: Try restarting R, clearing all output and running again.